StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing SMEMBERS (5000ms)?
I can see this error in my logs:

StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing SMEMBERS
(5000ms), inst: 206, qu: 204, qs: 0, aw: True, bw: Starting, rs:
ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, serverEndpoint:
localhost:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName:
RedisConnection:localhost:6379, IOCP:
(Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=12,Max=1000), WORKER:
(Busy=50,Free=32717,Min=12,Max=32767), v: 2.2.79.4591

I'm trying to figure out what is going wrong, however, by looking at these numbers I don't see any obvious reason. I'd appreciate some help.

how large is the set? if the set is oversized (i.e. simple bandwidth means you can't meet the timeout), you might need to use SetScan, which uses SSCAN rather than SMEMBERS. In redis-cli, SCARD yourkeykey should give you the number of elements, but the size of the set members is also relevant - there's a huge difference between a set of small integers vs a set of huge blob images

@MarcGravell thank you, I need to take a look at that.

you might also find slowlog useful on the server - it shows recent long-running redis server operations
